# Gif image view very, very laggy

Tags: android, gif

I am trying to disply a gif and it works great in emulator, but on my real device it's very laggy. I have a `Samsung Galaxy A3 - 2017`. I tried many libraries like `Glide library`, `Ion library` , `felipecsl.gifimageview library` but nothing worked. I have tried to display the gif from URL and even from drawable, raw and assets folders but nothing. Any ideas?

Currently I have this in my project:

Layout:

```
<com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
    android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavBar"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

GifImageView gifImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavBar);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.back:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Previous", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.start:
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Gif", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    new RetriveByteArray().execute("http://gifdanceparty.giphy.com/assets/dancers/smooch.gif");
                    gifImageView.startAnimation();
                    break;

                case R.id.stop:
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stop Gif", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gifImageView.stopAnimation();
                    break;

                case R.id.share:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.next:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

RetriveByteArray:

```
private class RetriveByteArray extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]>
{

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int nRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[10240];
                while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1)
                {
                    buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
                }
                buffer.flush();
                return buffer.toByteArray();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
        super.onPostExecute(bytes);
        gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the size of your gif file ?

Comment: It's just 333kb, 500x500, forgot to mention.

Comment: Do you have any: `Thread doing too much work, skipping xxx frames` issue or something like that in the logcat?

Comment: No, I dont have any of those... the logcat is clean from warnings and errors.

Comment: can you try `Fresco` library ? https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Comment: `Fresco` library works great!! Thanks! You can post this as an answer to mark it as good.

Comment: Instead of doing "fix edit" of your question you should post regular answer and accept it

Comment: What was the real reason of glich/lag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anybody who wants to know how I fixed it ( thanks to TGMCians answer)

Add dependencies:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.4.0'
// For animated GIF support
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.4.0'
```

Layout:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SimpleDraweeView mSimpleDraweeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fresco.initialize(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSimpleDraweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

 DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                            .setUri("https://media4.giphy.com/avatars/100soft/WahNEDdlGjRZ.gif")
                            .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                            .build();
                    mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
```